# Trouble with associatedtype constraints between protocols

Tags: ios, swift, associated-types

I have a protocol:

```swift
protocol CellContentViewButtonTappable: CellContentView {
    associatedtype ButtonData
    var delegate: (any CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate)? { get }
}
```

and a delegate:

```swift
protocol CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ButtonData
    func buttonTapped(_ data: ButtonData)
}
```

The point here is that when I call `delegate?.buttonTapped(_:)` from a class conforming to `CellContentViewButtonTappable` I want the `ButtonData` I pass back to be the same as the `ButtonData` that is in the class conforming to `CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate`. But I'm not quite sure how to do this. I've tried things like:

```swift
protocol CellContentViewButtonTappable: CellContentView {
    associatedtype ButtonData where ButtonData == CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate.ButtonData
    var delegate: (any CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate)? { get }
}
```

but going down this route has always resulted in the error:

```
Associated type 'ButtonData' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base
```

I feel like I'm close and [this change added in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) should allow me to do something like this, but I'm just not getting it right. Would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than associated type constraints in Swift 4, I think you need the [primary associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0346-light-weight-same-type-syntax.md) feature in Swift 5.7 instead.

Declare the delegate like this, with `ButtonData` as its primary associated type:

```
protocol CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate<ButtonData>: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ButtonData
    func buttonTapped(_ data: ButtonData)
}
```

In `CellContentViewButtonTappable`, you can then do:

```
var delegate: (any CellContentViewButtonTappableDelegate<ButtonData>)? { get }
```

Comment: I was just going to answer my own question with exactly this! Yep, perfect, thanks!